# Calculate with 3 fields

Tags: javascript

I apologise in advance for this noob question but I need to create a calculator with 3 fields (2 input and 1 output).

This is what I tried already:

```
<html>


<body>
<FORM>
    <script>
    function optellen()
    {
      var Getal1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
      var Getal2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value;
      var Getal3 = (parseInt(Getal1) + parseInt(Getal2);  

      document.getElementById("output").value = Getal3;
    }
    </script>


    <INPUT TYPE="text"   id="getal1" Size="22">

    <INPUT TYPE="text"   id="getal2" Size="22">

 <br>

    <button onclick="optellen();">optellen</button>
    <button> aftrekken </button>
    <button> delen </button>
    <button> vermeningvuldigen </button>

 <br>

    <INPUT TYPE="text"   id="output" Size="50">
 </FORM>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the problem apart from the syntax error of too many brackets? `var Getal3 = parseInt(Getal1,10) + parseInt(Getal2,10); `

Comment: Also I would put the script in the head of the page and not inside the form tags

Comment: I see an extra parenthesis here: var Getal3 = (parseInt(Getal1) + parseInt(Getal2);

Comment: Thanks guys, I feel really stupid now for asking such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unclosed parenthesis in your variable:

Change

```
var Getal3 = (parseInt(Getal1) + parseInt(Getal2);
```

to

```
var Getal3 = (parseInt(Getal1) + parseInt(Getal2));
```

And if you'd like to stay in the page after form submit(probably yes), add `return false;` to your function as @dejakob said in his answer.

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe it was this small problem, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yep, sometimes the answer is so simple. Don't forget to accept my answer, after the time period. :)

Comment: Or not seeing it was a simple mistake already posted as comment. Not worth saving in the SO knowledge base

Comment: @mplungjan Why didn't you then post your own answer?

Comment: Because it was not worth an answer and if there is an answer OP cannot delete the question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you press a button, the browser will by default redirect your page to the same url. This is because you putted everything in a form-tag. I easily solved this with onsubmit="return false;".

Secondly, there was a ) to short on this line:

```
var Getal3 = (parseInt(Getal1) + parseInt(Getal2));
```

/

```
<body>
<FORM onsubmit="return false;">
    <script>
    function optellen()
    {
      var Getal1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
      var Getal2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value;
      var Getal3 = (parseInt(Getal1) + parseInt(Getal2));  

      document.getElementById("output").value = Getal3;
    }
    </script>


    <INPUT TYPE="text"   id="getal1" Size="22">

    <INPUT TYPE="text"   id="getal2" Size="22">

 <br>

    <button onclick="optellen();">optellen</button>
    <button> aftrekken </button>
    <button> delen </button>
    <button> vermeningvuldigen </button>

 <br>

    <INPUT TYPE="text"   id="output" Size="50">
 </FORM>


</body>
```

Comment: Well spotted by the way - I always forget that `<button>` submits where `<input type="button"` does not

Comment: Hey thanks, you solved my other problem.